# How to convert any string to snake case using only base R

Tags: r, string

I am well aware of packages such as `snakecase` and `janitor` that allow for string conversion to snake case, but I wasn't able to find an answer using only base R *without* any other packages. What would be the most elegant way to do this?

For example, the following strings:

```
strings <- c("foo bar", "fooBar", "FooBar", "foo21bar",
             "lowerCamelCase", "ALL_CAPS", "IDontKNOWWhat_thisCASE_is")
```

Should be converted to snake case.

This essentially copies the behavior of `snakecase::to_snake_case()`

Comment: Do you mean from camel case to snake case or which strings do you have in mind?

Comment: any possible case, not only camel case, so all of these: "foo bar", "fooBar", "FooBar" should be converted to "foo_bar"

Comment: If you want the exact behavior with all it's nooks and corners, consider looking at the sourcecode: `snakecase::to_snake_case` which leads you to `snakecase::to_any_case`.

Answer (score 5):

We can use two `gsub` to do the job.

```
strings <- c("foo bar", "fooBar", "FooBar", "foo_bar")

gsub(" ", "_", tolower(gsub("(.)([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2", strings)))
[1] "foo_bar" "foo_bar" "foo_bar" "foo_bar"
```

Comment: this wouldn't work for "foo123bar". See my edit to the original question.

Comment: @DavidBudzynski Sorry for missing so many patterns in my attempt. The source code of `to_any_case` (or `to_snake_case`) contains a few hundred lines of codes to consider different string patterns, I'm not sure if there's any "elegant" way to do it in base R

Comment: no problem! I will probably investigate the code and maybe produce a base version based on that, thanks!